# Ubuntu alternative for Windows Start > search or OS X Finder?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm looking to add a **search** with autocomplete for launching different applications under Ubuntu, something similar to Windows 7 Start menu > search... or to the Finder from OS X.

This should be something you could add to the desktop bar.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6135/alternatives-to-os-xs-spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Probably [gnome-do](http://do.davebsd.com/) is what you want
[image]